# How should I store an image inside an exe using Eclipse for C/C++?

Tags: windows

I'm doing this because I want a single exe to set the desktop wallpaper, which requires me to create a temporary image from what I want to be stored in the exe to be loaded as the wallpaper.

Answer (score 0):

You can link resources into an EXE.  Standard practice is:

- To have a `.rc` file in your project that declares the resources: bitmaps, icons, strings, files (including not bmp types), version info, etc...
- Using the `rc.exe` tool that comes with the Windows SDK, compile your `.rc` file into a `.res` files
- Link your .res file into your EXE. I think you just pass the .res to the link command line like you would any other .obj file.
- At runtime, you can use [various Win32 functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/resources-functions) to load these resource elements in as a handle or obtain a memory pointer.

Visual Studio's project environment makes this easy. Not sure about how you'd do this in Eclipse.